# Simulink: replace existing subsystem with another one

Tags: simulink

How do i replace an existing SubSystem in a given model with another SubSystem from another model.

I tried commands like:
Simulink.SubSystem.copyContentsToBlockDiagram(subsys, bdiag)
replace_block

but nothing worked (maybe I used it wrong).

Remarks:
I am using matlab 2011b.

Comment: See the doc for `replace_block`.

Comment: @PhilGoddard, thanks for your answer, unfortunately it did not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That depends what you're doing, which you haven't told us.